# Unable to publish the page?

Tags: 2013

> 2014-12-01 08:52:52,485 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start
>   processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-96-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Processing
>   Phase failed.  null   at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_71]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the
>   StorageManagerFactory     at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:88)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:56)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:90)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:145)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  ... 9 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find
>   configuration file: [ preview_dao_bundle.xml ]    at
>   com.tridion.configuration.XMLConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(XMLConfigurationReader.java:92)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.storage.configuration.BundleConfigurationLoader.configure(BundleConfigurationLoader.java:43)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.services.BaseService.(BaseService.java:113)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:104)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84)
>   ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    ... 21 common frames omitted

Comment: Can you please edit your question and clarify the problem and what log you have supplied. It will also be interesting to know if publishing worked before or if this is your first attempt in setting it up that is failing already?

Comment: check whether destination folder have proper permissions.

Comment: if this question is related to http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/unable-publish-page please indicate so that we can delete one of them. Having two similair questions open by different users is not going to speed up getting a result.

Comment: It looks like your storage is configured for preview/Experience Manager, but you're missing the required JAR files. Either remove the bundle configuration from the storage conf, or add the missing jars.

Comment: Version of Tridion? General information regarding the setup? Does it happen for all/some pages? What has been tried so far to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Deployer is looking for this file and not finding it in the config folder:  Can't find configuration file: [ preview_dao_bundle.xml ]

If you don't have any custom deployer code or custom storage extensions installed then it is  probably easier to start to create a new deployer instance instead of debugging this one.  Simply follow the instructions here, http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html

There are also config file examples provided in the install files location these days, so best to use those examples instead of Nuno's config files from his site.

Finally, always check the logback logging location, make sure to set it for each deployer you have, and set it to info or debug for extra logging info.